# How to use GPS to get the real time position?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I already install the cordova with Jboss tools (IDE: Eclipse); and I need to learn how I can use GPS to get my real time position like the app google maps in mobile phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the current position you need to install cordova geolocation plugin, then use the following code

```
function CheckCurrentLocation(){

  if( navigator.geolocation )    {
      var options={maximumAge:60000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy:true };
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, fail);
              }  
              else  {          alert("Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.");  }  }

function success(position)  {
     alert( "latitude :"+position.coords.latitude +", longititude : "+position.coords.longitude); 

         var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            writeAddressName(userLatLng);
   function writeAddressName(userLatLng) {
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({
          "location": userLatLng
        },
        function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
           {

          alert("first address is : "+results[0].address_components[0].long_name);
               alert("Street Name is : "+results[0].address_components[1].long_name);
               alert("CityName  is : "+results[0].address_components[2].long_name);
               alert("Dristic name is : "+results[0].address_components[3].long_name);
               alert("State name is : "+results[0].address_components[4].long_name);
               alert("Country name is : "+results[0].address_components[5].long_name);

            }
          else{
            alert( "Unable to retrieve your address" );
            }
        });
      }
      function fail(){
      alert(" Fail!, To find the location");
      }
      }
```

In the above code google.maps.Geocoder(); is used to find the address from google maps, to work it you must include following scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?AIzaSyA2E0vmaArSYL8UH5-NFzYfMsx7QvGK6Lg&sensor=true"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3&key= your key" ></script>
```

Hope it will helps you